# difference in charging battery of different Ah

Tags: battery-charging, charger

Can i use a lower Ah battery charger(say 20,30)to charge a higher Ah battery ie 110Ah?What are the consequences?
What is the  difference in  the charger circuit in both case?

Comment: It's a matter of energy transfer (see the amp-hour). Ask yourself if and how you'd fill a glass of water with a tea-spoon.

Comment: Non-trivial chargers will have safety features implemented to prevent overcharging in case of failure. For example, if the battery is not fully charged after say twice the expected time, the charger may stop charging and signal an error condition.

Comment: Your battery charger will not be rated in Ah. Do you mean a 20-30 _A_ charger?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in theory, but won't be very useful in practice.

First, you can't just connect batteries together.  The charging battery needs the right combination of volts and amps.  Even if the two batteries are of the same chemistry, and therefore will have the same voltage at the same state of charge, just connecting them is still a bad idea.  The current can be very high, dependent only on the internal resistance of the batteries.

To do this correctly would require a switching regulator that can convert the source battery's volts and amps to what it takes to charge the destination battery.  That is doable enough, but will lose some energy in the transfer.

However, the bigger issue here is that there just isn't that much energy in a 20 Ah battery compared to what a 110 Ah battery (assuming same types) can hold.  You'd have to use a bunch of smaller batteries to charge up the larger one.  I suppose this could be done if the larger battery is someplace fixed and remote, so you shuttle power there by using a set of smaller batteries.  Again, this works in theory, although there really should be easier ways to get this accomplished in practice.  This is like filling the gas tank in your car by walking back and forth between the car and gas station with a 1 liter bottle.  You'd eventually get there, but other methods will be easier.

Comment: I think he's asking about using a small mains battery charger to charge a large capacity battery - not charge a large battery from a small one.

Answer (score 0):

Provided the charger is off the correct voltage, yes. The charger should be designed to limit the current to a safe value for the charger. The charge current should be stated on the charger and will be rated in A (amps) and not Ah (amp-hours).

To estimate the charge time:

$$Charge time (hours) = \frac{BatteryRating (Ah)}{ChargeCurrent (A)}$$

Comment: I would add that the charger needs to be for the correct battery chemistry, or 'interesting' results may await.